# Android application as service

Tags: java, android

I want to create an android application **without Activity** and via **intent** the application need to be started.

Use Case 1 : I was facing issues while invoking the application from another android application were the application is not getting invoked and there is no error logs as well in the console.

Use Case 2: I was trying to do it on RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED.In this way also it is not working

Application to be run as service Manifest File:

```html
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="something.boo.com.diagnosticservicepai" android:sharedUserId="android.uid.system">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name">
    <receiver
        android:name=".BootDeviceReceiver"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>

    <service
        android:name=".SomeService"
        android:exported="true"></service>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**BootDeviceReceiver.java**:

```
public class BootDeviceReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    private static final String TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER = "BOOT_SomeService";

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

        String action = intent.getAction();

        String message = "BootDeviceReceiver onReceive, action is " + action;

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, action);

        if(Intent.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED.equals(action))
        {
            startServiceDirectly(context);

            //startServiceByAlarm(context);
        }
    }

    /* Start RunAfterBootService service directly and invoke the service every 10 seconds. */
    private void startServiceDirectly(Context context)
    {
        try {
            //while (true) {
                String message = "BootDeviceReceiver onReceive start service directly.";

                Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, message);

                // This intent is used to start background service. The same service will be invoked for each invoke in the loop.
                Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, SomeService.class);
                context.startService(startServiceIntent);

                // Current thread will sleep one second.
                Thread.sleep(10000);
            //}
        }catch(InterruptedException ex)
        {
            Log.e(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, ex.getMessage(), ex);
        }
    }


    /* Create an repeat Alarm that will invoke the background service for each execution time.
     * The interval time can be specified by your self.  */
    private void startServiceByAlarm(Context context)
    {
        // Get alarm manager.
        AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);

        // Create intent to invoke the background service.
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, SomeService.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        long intervalTime = 60*1000;

        String message = "Start service use repeat alarm. ";

        Toast.makeText(context, message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_BROADCAST_RECEIVER, message);

        // Create repeat alarm.
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, startTime, intervalTime, pendingIntent);
    }
}
```

**SomeService.java:**

```html
public class SomeService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE = "BOOT_SomeService";

    private someAIDLImpl impl = new someAIDLImpl();

    MediaPlayer player;

    private class SomeAIDLImpl extends ISomeBaseService.Stub{
        
    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE, "SomeService onCreate() method.");

    }


    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {

        Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "onBind(..)");
        //return null;
        return impl;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.d("MESS", "onStartCommand call");
        String message = "SomeService onStartCommand() method.";

        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        Log.d(TAG_BOOT_EXECUTE_SERVICE, "SomeService onStartCommand() method.");

        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    /*private void startService(Context context) {
     
        if(rc < 0){
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "failed");
            return;
        }else {
            Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "success ");

        }
        Log.v(this.getClass().getName(), "Service started at "+ new java.sql.Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()).toString());*//*

        player = MediaPlayer.create(this, Settings.System.DEFAULT_RINGTONE_URI);
        player.setLooping(true);
        player.start();
    }*/
}
```

Comment: instead of copy-pasting *all* your code here, paste only the necessary code where you see problems. Also, what is the question? Something like "I would like to accomplish xxx, but I can't because yyy, while I would expect zzz to happen. So, how can I www?" where www is your question.

Answer (score 0):

You must have an activity if you want to receive `BOOT_COMPLETED`. An app is in the ["stopped" state](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/android-3.1#launchcontrols) when initially installed, and after being force closed, until the user has launched one of its activities. When an app is in the stopped state, none of its broadcast receivers will ever be called.